# Is dylib the same as dll in the windows?

Tags: macos

I am reading some documents of some make systems. I have an impression dylib should be the same as dll in windows. However, it mentioned there is a loadable module concept, what exactly does it mean in Mac?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, dylib is a dynamic library, which is the same concept as a Windows dll.

An application can use functions at run-time, such as [dlopen](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/dlopen.3.html) and [dlsym](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/dlsym.3.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/3/dlsym) to load a module and find an address of a symbol.